# IE aborting plugin script causes JQuery problems on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am working on a https website and a plugin totally unrelated to my site (requesting http elements) was causing security problems.

I have disabled (Windows) Internet Options -> Security -> Mixed Mode (so that we cannot fetch http resources from a https site).

With this restriction in place IE9 will abort a script run by the plugin requesting http elements whenever I'm on a https site (in this case the offending plugin is http://www.freemake.com/ video downloader).
Console output:
*SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://download.freemake.com/images/arrow.png 
-link to my https site-
SCRIPT16388: Operation aborted*
This abort happens **after**/end-of $(document).ready(...).

What happens next however is causing me some headaches...
*SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'*
This is refering to the $.cookie function (it also happens with many other jQuery functions).

Various functions of jQuery are seemingly disabled or removed. I run some console logs before the above abort operation:
*LOG: jQuery.cookie  >>> true 
LOG: $.cookie  >>> true 
LOG: jQuery  >>> true 
LOG: $  >>> true*

As you can see they exist. After the abort operation I call the logs again:

*LOG: jQuery.cookie  >>> false 
LOG: $.cookie  >>> false 
LOG: jQuery  >>> true 
LOG: $  >>> true*

How could the abort operation of the plugin script affect my site? The site is hosting it's own jQuery lib.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle so we can test it?

Comment: I can't share the source I'm afraid at this point, if it was my own property then I wouldn't hesitate. I'm not sure how share a 'general' sample of what I'm sitting on here.

Comment: have you tried defining the url as `//download.freemake.com/images/arrow.png`
instead of `http://download.freemake.com/images/arrow.png`

Comment: The http ... arrow.png request is coming from an installed IE add-on that is unrelated to the https website I'm working on. We can't (choose not to) control what plugins our users have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely they are sharing the same global variable "$" to remove it from global scope use

jQuery.noConflict();

then assign it to new variable like this

$j = jQuery;

Comment: Another solution would be to use a self invoking anonymous function and pass the $ as an internal variable  `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: Looking into this. Since the $ variable is so widely used in the script I want to 'reset it' as soon as IE9 removes it (so that my code can still reliably use $ for jQuery).

Comment: Initial result is promising and my page loads successfully. Now whenever I change the page within the site the add-on re-injects its script forcing IE9 to remove it again (which again invalidates the $ variable). Now I need to figure out a smart place to reset $/call .noConflict().

Comment: This is the correct answer, and really the only thing you can do in this situation. The only thing I'd add to this answer is that the crappy browser extension should be fixed not your code. You may even want to tell your users to uninstall it. You should definitely file a bug report with them and probably send scathing email.